# Equation reference undefined when using \cref and package{amsmath}

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, amsmath, cleveref

When I attempt to reference an equation using `\cref{..}` while also using the package amsmath the references appear as `??` in the outputted pdf. For example

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref} %for cref
\usepackage{amsmath} %for sub equation numbers and words within equations (\text)

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:solve}
    x^2 - 5 x + 6 = 0 
    \end{equation}


    Ref: \ref{eq:solve}

    CRef: \cref{eq:solve}

\end{document}
```

I get the output:

[image]

However if the `\usepackage{amsmath}` is commented out the `\cref` works correctly.

[image]

Is it possible to use both together successfully?

Comment: You have to load `cleveref` last, even after `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! That solved the problem. If you post that as an answer I will accept it

Comment: you might want to consider using `amsmath`'s `\eqref` instead of just `\ref`.  `\eqref` adds parentheses around the reference, and ensures that they (and the reference itself) are always upright.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Are you refering to my line `Ref: \ref{eq:solve}`, if so thats just in there to prove that normal references are still working; that only cref that was troublesome

Comment: @RichardTingle -- yes, that's what i was referring to, and i understand that it was only for illustration.  but some authors find the parenthesized cross reference preferable to the "eq." representation.  (it can probably be changed, but not everyone knows about that.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fair enough, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I tried to look for other questions with the same problem and found none. So here's an answer: load `cleveref` last.

From the documentation:

> The `cleveref` package is loaded in the usual way, by putting the line
>
> ```
> \usepackage{cleveref}
> ```
>
> in your document’s preamble. However, care must be taken when using `cleveref` in conjunction with other packages that modify LaTeX’s referencing system (see Section 11). Basically, cleveref must be loaded *last*.

The problem is that `amsmath` modifies the referencing system, in order to cope with `\tag`, for instance. So `cleveref` has to hook into the redefined macros, rather than the original ones. By loading `amsmath` after `cleveref` you don't give the package the chance to know `amsmath` is also requested.

Comment: In my case it was below `amsmath`, but above `mathtools` and a couple of `\newtheorem` definitions. Frustrating to have the order matter like that.

Comment: @ThomasAhle As a general rule, I recommend to first load all packages (`cleveref` last, of course) and then do settings.

Comment: Makes sense, but then there are other packages, like `autonum` that also want to be loaded last :(